# Using tensorboard histograms with tf.contrib.layers

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

Im trying to understand if there is a way to get a histogram of the weights in a [fully_connected](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/fully_connected) layer from `tf.contrib.layers`. In the documentation there is no obv way to get the weights.

So my question is, how can I visualise the weights from layers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this block in your code:

```
for var in tf.trainable_variables: # or tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'your desired scope name'):
tf.summary.histogram(var.name, var)
with tf.name_scope('summaries'):
    mean = tf.reduce_mean(var)
    tf.summary.scalar('mean', mean)
with tf.name_scope('stddev'):
    stddev = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(var - mean)))
tf.summary.scalar('stddev', stddev)
tf.summary.scalar('max', tf.reduce_max(var))
tf.summary.scalar('min', tf.reduce_min(var))
```

Then, you need to add:

```
merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()   
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(config.model_dir)
```

to collect the summaries.